# In which cases checking whether boolean function is monotone is obvious?

Tags: boolean-algebra, monotone-functions

There are tasks, homeworks, where a student should determine if the boolean function is monotone.

My question is simple: Do I understand correctly , that, when the boolean function is given by truth table or it’s vector of values it is pretty easy to determine wether it monotone or not? — you just need if there is no zero after 1 (function is decreasing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any pair of rows where one row is a binary increment of the other (meaning you've only changed a 0 to a 1 in one or more places), the output of the function in the "higher" row should be greater than or equal to the "lower" row.

Also, the function is monotone if there is no case where an increase in input leads to a decrease in output.